# Excel 2010: Open a file that contains more than 1M rows?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an excel file provided in .xlsx format. The person who sent me the file states that there are over 1.2M records contained in the file. However, when I open up the file, I see a little over 1M records. I was instructed to open the file in Notepad, save as a .txt file and then I will be able to view all 1.2M records.

Is this possible for .xlsx files? I've done some research that states this is possible for .csv files but am wondering if I need to request a .csv file or .txt file that actually contains all of the records.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: 1048576 - is the max rows I see in a blank Excel 2007 file (.xlsx) I don't know if you can expand that or not

Comment: I think the sender is mistaken.  The file can't contain that many records.  Ask if they can provide you a plain text or delimited file. There are some functions you could run to import the data to (several) worksheets in an XLS* file.

Comment: I wouldn't accept any files from this person in the first place, because if they knew what they were doing - and that step was necessary, they would have just sent you a compressed CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [limit of 1,048,576 rows](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx) that can be *viewed/accessed* in Excel 2007/2010.

In this case the file contains 1.2M million rows and thus, *while the rows exist in the file, they cannot be viewed/accessed in Excel*.

The person providing the data is suggesting to *not use Excel* to open the files.

One possible approach to see the raw data - assuming it is an "unpacked .xslx"<sup>1</sup> file - is to use Notepad to open the file (if Notepad doesn't work, Write might). Here are several approaches to do such:

1. Right Click on the file and go to "Open with -> Choose default program .." then choose Notepad (make sure to *uncheck* "Always use ..");
2. Rename the file extension to ".txt" so that it will be associated with a normal editor (perhaps Notepad?) by default;
3. Launch Notepad and then "Open" said file.

If the data was provided in CSV, all the rows could still *not* all be viewed in Excel (e.g. after an import) due to said limit. If this file is an "unpacked .xsls" then the data *already* is normal text and the file having a .xsls extension (vs .txt) is largely irrelevant - the extension exists for program/file association.

Another option is to see if a different spreadsheet program (e.g. [Open Office Calc](http://www.openoffice.org/product/calc.html), [Kingsoft Office Suite](http://www.kingsoftstore.com/kingsoft-office-freeware.html)) is able to display this many rows. YMMV.

---

<sup>1</sup> Not all ".xslx" files are the same and Excel is pretty lenient on the data format contained in files with this extension that can be opened. In this case the other person sounds confident that it is reasonable to view this file as raw text - even if dealing with the data will likely be cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried using Notepad to open but it crashes the program. The excel file is also encrypted? Does that make a difference? Thank you for your response.

Comment: @mrdaby If Notepad crashes, Write might work. However, if the Excel file is encrypted or using Write displays "gibberish" then .. I got nothing for you :) In this case the assumptions I went on in my reply - mainly that the other person believed that said file could be "opened raw" - may be incorrect. While a CSV file would *not* work any better *in* Excel, it would ensure that the export was only "plain text", at the very least.

Answer (score 2):

XLSX files are actually just a set of compressed files and folders. If you want to see the raw data, you can rename the file with a ZIP extention and open it.

You should see a folder called "XL" and inside it will be folder called "Worksheets" and inside it will be an XML file with the name of each worksheet.

If you open it, it will load in your browser which might take a long time so I suggest you get something like Notepadd++. Much faster at opening up large files.

But, if they think they put more than the 1,048,576 rows in it, they are wrong. It is a limitation of MS Excel (at least with recent versions).